# Filter in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 selects with ng-options. I would like the 2nd select to iterate over the `values` field of the choosen `name`.

The only solution I found is to select the object itself and not only the name field in the first select (something like `d as d.name for d in data`)
but for consistency I'd rather not.

Can I use a filter or something like that to solve this problem ?

```js
angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{ 
    name : "john",
    values : ["Hello", "World"]
   }, {
    name : "peter",
    values : ["Bonjour", "le", "monde"]
   }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<label>Name :</label>
<select ng-model="name" ng-options="d.name as d.name for d in data"></select>
<label>Value :</label>
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="d as d for d in data"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{ 
    name : "john",
    values : ["Hello", "World"]
   }, {
    name : "peter",
    values : ["Bonjour", "le", "monde"]
   }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<label>Name :</label>
<select ng-model="name" ng-options="d.name for d in data"></select>
<label>Value : </label>
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="d as d for d in name.values"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is now $scope.name === {{$index}} and not the name itself

Comment: This will set value of `$scope.name` as 0, 1, which is what op doesn't want to do probably.

Comment: not hard to have `$scope.getName = function(id){ return $scope.data[id] }`

Comment: @SteevePitis I need this in a form with many fields. I'd like to not have a special behavior (form.value = $scope.data[form.value] as get JS getter/setter are not well supported accros browsers) for one of the fields

Comment: And what about the entire object ? I've updated my answer. so u have `form.value.name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this is a working way:

```js
angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{ 
    name : "john",
    values : ["Hello", "World"]
   }, {
    name : "peter",
    values : ["Bonjour", "le", "monde"]
   }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<label>Name :</label>
<select ng-model="name" ng-options="d.name as d.name for d in data"></select>
<label>Value :</label>
<select ng-model="value" ng-repeat="d in data" ng-if="name === d.name" ng-options="val for val in d.values"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the behavior I want :), also I find this way a bit "dirty". If nobody comes up with a cleaner solution, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Actually he have only 2 Objects in `data` but iterate with a ngIf is not a good choice in my opinion !

Comment: I think is is just a dummy data @SteevePitis

Comment: @IggY If there is, I would love to know as well :)